# Can I substitute \u00A0 and line feed sequences by JavaScript replace?

Tags: javascript, replace, special-characters

Using jQuery text I received a string that contains a lot of \u00A0 characters.  Also, I received a lot of \r\n\r\n … in sequence.

To output I need to replace the \u00A0 character by white space globally.  I also need from the \r\n sequence like \r\n\r\n\r\n leave only one sign \n.

Is it possible to do this with JavaScript replace?

Comment: Wouldn't it be soooo much easier to just try it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\u00A0/g, " ").replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "\n");
```

Comment: The part about replacing \u00A0/ worked, changing a series of carriage returns did not. I will ask another question

Comment: Assuming you had other whitespaces in between your linebreak, you'd need to use `/\s*?[\r\n]\s*/g`. I though you meant "concurrently" by "*in sequence*".

Comment: function stringTrim(s) {
                return s.replace(/^(\s|\u00A0)+|(\s|\u00A0)+$/g, "");
            }